# Check DbNull before casting C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, sqlconnection

I am trying query the SQL Server Database and return the response in JSON. I am trying the code below

```
      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
            command.Parameters.Add("@ROOM_Data", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters["@ROOM_Data"].Value = ROOM;
            connection.Open();
            List<DatabaseResult> records = new List<DatabaseResult>();

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var row = new DatabaseResult
                    {
                        request_id = (int)reader["request_id"],
                        room = (string)reader["room"],
                        jrs_no = (int)reader["jrs_no"],
                        submit_date = (DateTime)reader["submit_date"],
                        sample_no = (int)reader["sample_no"],
                        animal_id = (string)reader["animal_id"],
                        pen_id = (string)reader["pen_id"],
                        ped_no = (string)reader["ped_no"],
                        gender = (string)reader["gender"],
                        dob = (DateTime)reader["dob"],
                        parent_mating = (string)reader["parent_mating"],
                        generation = (string)reader["generation"],
                        allele = (string)reader["allele"],
                        status_type = (string)reader["status_type"],
                        genotype = (string)reader["genotype"],
                        comments = (string)reader["comments"],
                        completion_date = (DateTime)reader["completion_date"],
                        disposition = (string)reader["disposition"],

                    };
                    records.Add(row);
                }
                return Ok(records);
```

Here I am having an issue when there is a null in any field. I tried to look in to other forums can I understand we need to check each column if it is null or not before casting. But I am checking if I can do through the method which can handle all the cases?

Comment: put a `?` after your datatype i.e (int?) and declare your variables in the class with `?`

Comment: @Boxed I am sorry I am not able to follow, can you provide me an example?

Comment: Use DBNull.Value to verify in C#

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Can you please give me an example.

Comment: Cor, 6 answers and not a single person has suggested using a modern, sensible data access strategy. Please take a look at something like an Entity Framework tutorial. Ramming button click handlers full of sql strings and and reader.getxxx is so last century. Your entire code bloc can be reduced to something like `var x = context.Rooms.Where(r => r.id == ROOM);` and it won't explode if something happens to be null

Comment: @CaiusJard why do you think this question is related to EF, that's not even a tag

Comment: @MrinalKamboj so, you didn't understand my comment, then?

Comment: @CaiusJard you can elaborate, since accepted answer is correct and there's no dbcontext that I can see

Comment: The point I was getting at is that those of us who know have a responsibility to at least try and guide junior developers into doing things better. SO has an intrinsic problem in that it encourages solutions to questions exactly as asked, even when it's clear that the problem could be far better solved in different ways. Being constrained to only solving the critical problem with the terrible way the questioner has chosen to do something doesn't help them learn and improve as a coder, it only reinforces a belief that their chosen solution is right once they get over some side problem.It has ->

Comment: -> a name, actually; the XY problem. Newbie devises a substandard solution to a problem, encounters some issue with their solution, seeks help in resolving the issue. A mentor programmer worth his salt would actually say "take a step back, what is the ACTUAL problem you're trying to solve? OK.. I suggest..". When I see yet another question with some button click handler stuffed full of sql-in-string statements, and datareaders, I'm motivated to say "you know, we can do data access much better these days". After all, we don't save a file by manipulating the hard disk sectors/FAT directly!?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check column value against `DBNull.Value` like this:

```
request_id = (reader["request_id"] == DBNull.Value) ? default(int) : (int)reader["request_id"];
```

If you want to simplify the process to all columns, create an extension method which compares against `DBNull.Value` like this example:

```
// using DBNull.Value comparison
public static T GetValue<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, string columnName)
{
    var value = reader[columnName]; // read column value

    return value == DBNull.Value ? default(T) : (T)value;
}

// alternative using GetOrdinal and IsDBNull
public static T GetValue<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, string columnName) 
{
    int index = reader.GetOrdinal(columnName); // read column index

    return reader.IsDBNull(index) ? default(T) : (T)reader.GetValue(index);
}
```

Usage example:

```
request_id = GetValue<int>(reader, "request_id");
```

Comment: `SqlDataReader` can be of type `IDataReader` if you want to use with `DataTableReader` also

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
public static class SqlReaderExtention {

     public static T GetValue<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, string fieldName) {
        int columnIndex = reader.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
        if (reader.IsDBNull(columnIndex)) {
           return default(T);
        }

        return (T)reader.GetValue(columnIndex);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have to use a datareader and you are defining your own raw sql, which this appears to be the case then in the sql you could wrap modify your sql statement to use ISNULL checks in the select part.
eg - ensure a string column returns and empty string ('') instead of NULL

```
select isnull(foo,'') from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `int` does not handle null values when you cast it.

Try

`sample_no = (int?)reader["sample_no"]`

and in your class `DatabaseResult`

declare `sample_no` as `int? sample_no`

`int?` means its nullable int where if you pass null values to it, it won't throw an exception.

another method would be is `int.TryParse` where it will place 0 instead if it detected that it was null value.

Comment: This is not a good idea, since you are changing the type of the property, which may not be feasible

Answer (score 0):

```
request_id = reader["request_id"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (int?)reader["request_id"] ,
room = reader["room"].ToString(),
jrs_no = reader["jrs_no"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (int?)reader["jrs_no"] ,
submit_date = reader["submit_date"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (DateTime?)reader["submit_date"],
sample_no = reader["sample_no"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (int?)reader["sample_no"],
animal_id = reader["animal_id"].ToString(),
pen_id = reader["pen_id"].ToString(),
ped_no = reader["ped_no"].ToString(),
gender = reader["gender"].ToString(),
dob = reader["dob"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (DateTime?)reader["dob"],
parent_mating = reader["parent_mating"].ToString(),
generation = reader["generation"].ToString(),
allele = reader["allele"].ToString(),
status_type = reader["status_type"].ToString(),
genotype = reader["genotype"].ToString(),
comments = reader["comments"].ToString(),
completion_date = reader["completion_date"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (DateTime?)reader["completion_date"],
disposition = reader["disposition"].ToString(),
```

database null value you can manage as you like. int and datetime variables change to int? and datetime? respectively or you can set default value in case if db value null

Comment: I tried this and I get Error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?` and `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?`

Comment: for example , submit_date  has type DateTime, if you want submit_date to take null value , change to DateTIme? or set default (depends on your logic )

Comment: I recomend you to manage situation with db null value and carefully use default value 
Let say you have a field StatusCode which takes  0 (success) or 1 (fail). In database StatusCode is null (undefined) but you consume it as 0. In this case you read undefined status as success. It can cause to wrong behavior of your programm

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful parsing an `int` to your code because it could return you an error.

Why don't you try before you proceed to run it in code behind and fixed it in your query using `isnull`.

`select isnull(yourNumField,'0')`

Comment: All the null are in the varchar filed not in the DateTime or int filed

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the Extension Method option mentioned for general usage, if you just need a quick check against a DB Null for a value that could be null, I would recommend something like this:

```
if (rdr["request_id"] != DBNull.Value)
   RequestID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["request_id"]);
```

Or, you could be more concise, and provide a default value:

```
RequestID = (rdr["request_id"] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(rdr["request_id"]) : 0;
```